# Compile error netbeans,cygwin at C

Tags: c, netbeans, cygwin, netbeans-7

I tried right-clicking 'project->properties->linker' and adding all the libraries from the `w32api` folder, but that did not help. It still fails after three days of trying!

> "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS=
>   .build-conf make[1]: Entering directory
>   `/cygdrive/c/Users/Νικολας/Desktop/CppApplication_1'
>
> "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
>   dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x_1-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
>
> make[2]: Entering directory
>   `/cygdrive/c/Users/Νικολας/Desktop/CppApplication_1'
>
> mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x_1-Windows
>
> rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x_1-Windows/byreferencemain.o.d
>
> gcc.exe    -c -g -w -MMD -MP -MF
>   build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x_1-Windows/byreferencemain.o.d -o
>   build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x_1-Windows/byreferencemain.o byreferencemain.c
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/cygdrive/c/Users/Νικολας/Desktop/CppApplication_1'
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:67: recipe for target`.build-conf' failed
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory
>   `/cygdrive/c/Users/Νικολας/Desktop/CppApplication_1'
>   nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target`.build-impl' failed
>
> make[2]: *** No rule to make target
>   `../../../../cygwin/lib/libaclui.a', needed by`
>   dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x_1-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe'.  Stop.
>
> make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
>
> make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> make[2]: * No rule to make target >../../../../cygwin/lib/libaclui.a'

looks like you not only need libaclui.a library,
but this file should be placed at the exact place,
make sure that such file there by type command:

```
ls ../../../../cygwin/lib/libaclui.a
```

in cygwin console